# How to create a dropdown nav with Laravel and Tailwind CSS

Tags: laravel, navigation, dropdown, breeze, tailwind-css

This is for the benefit of those of you who have Googled "**dropdown nav with Laravel Breeze**" (or variations) and have not found satisfactory solutions.

While in the middle of creating a UI for Spatie's [Permissions](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/introduction) package in my Laravel 8.x project, I wanted to make a dropdown nav for its various parts. After a lot of searching around, I was not able to come up with a simple and elegant way to accomplish this, so I scrutinized what was already there and figured it out.  Perhaps I wasn't looking in the right place, but so be it. I welcome any comments that will make this better.

First, make your routes in `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/roles', AdminController::class . '@roles')->name('roles');
Route::get('/permissions', AdminController::class . '@permissions')->name('permissions');
Route::get('/user_roles', AdminController::class . '@userRoles')->name('user_roles');
```

Next, inside your `navigation.blade.php`:

```
<!-- Admin Dropdown -->
<div class="hidden sm:flex sm:items-center sm:ml-6 pt-1">
    <x-dropdown align="right" width="48">
        <x-slot name="trigger">
            <button class="flex items-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                <div>Admin</div>

                <div class="ml-1">
                    <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </button>
        </x-slot>

        <x-slot name="content">
            <x-dropdown-link :href="route('roles')" active="request()->routeIs('roles')">
                {{ __('Roles') }}
            </x-dropdown-link>
            <x-dropdown-link :href="route('permissions')" active="request()->routeIs('permissions')">
                {{ __('Permissions') }}
            </x-dropdown-link>
            <x-dropdown-link :href="route('user_roles')" active="request()->routeIs('user_roles')">
                {{ __('User Roles') }}
            </x-dropdown-link>
        </x-slot>
    </x-dropdown>
</div>
```

NOTE: This assumes you have a `navigation.blade.php` already in place.  This is automatically created when you install [Laravel Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze).

Comment: I also need the solution